# Webpack not working for simple project with npm start

Tags: reactjs, webpack

This is my package file and webpack configuration.  I'm learning the technology but this isn't working.  I receive the following error for a blank canvas project.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks,

**Error message**

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 6:16
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import App from './App';
| 
> ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.32.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin()]
};
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>hello</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I now have the following webpack.config.js

**Update - complete file**

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin()]
};
```

After this change and after running npm install I get the following error when running npm start

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:
   object { defaultRules?, exprContextCritical?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?, noParse?, rules?, strictExportPrese
nce?, strictThisContextOnImports?, unknownContextCritical?, unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, w
rappedContextCritical?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp? }
   -> Options affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).
 - configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should be an non-empty string.
   -> A non-empty string
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! boilerplate@1.0.0 start: `webpack --mode development --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the boilerplate@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

**Update 2**

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
            loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin()]
};
```

Error received with this version of the file

```
[./src/index.js] 3.16 KiB {main} [not cacheable] [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'
 babel-loader@8 requires Babel 7.x (the package '@babel/core'). If you'd like to use Babel 6.x ('babel-core'), you should install 'babel-loader@7'.
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:613:15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your webpack
...your code in webpack ...

```
,resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

try `npm install` in your folder after that again use `npm start`

Comment: I have tried this and included the error message I receive in the question update

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your property

`module:{
loaders`

is not correct, it should be **modules->rules**. Secondly, you do not have any JSX in folders, You have App.js, so your rules, should test it and load appropriate loaders for it, which would we be babel-loader with presets set to react

```
 module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            }
```

To tell babel to use react as its presets, either you specify in above config or create a **.babelrc** file with below content in it.

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
  }
```

After this, you should be good to go

Comment: I do have a babelrc file but the contents is {
    "presets": [
        "env",
        "react"
    ] 
}

Comment: I've updated my question with the complete webpack.config.js file.

Comment: any suggestions?